With three people in a sentence, how to refer to the second one in the next sentence?
Let A, B and C be people with long names.
If I write their full names in the sentence "A and B are talking together." it is easy, for the sake of brevity, to mention one of them in the next sentence, by referring to A as "the former" or to B as "the latter".
But suppose have the sentence "A is describing B in front of C." What should I use, for brevity, if I want to mention B in the next sentence? "The former" would be A, "the latter" would C be!?
Please note that English is not my first language...

EDIT
Well, maybe I should give exactly the context of my question.
In another community, I wrote, not verbatim, but essentially
Bob Shaftoe was not addressing John Churchill but discussing him with Captain Barnes. Also the former ( ? not "latter" , that was Barnes, but "former" should be Shaftoe ?) was not yet Duke of Marlborough but at that time only Earl.
The person I meant in the second sentence was John Churchill, the bane of the french armies.
What would have been the best way to write this ?

A is describing B to C: "They are a talented/ complex/generous ...'." There is no word corresponding to 'former' 'latter'.

@EdwinAshworth I think you missed my point.  I used the verb "describing" just to have a short sentence with three different people. Any sentence with three people would do. "A was walking with B when they met C", "A was sitting on a bench, B and C stopped to greet him", any sentence with A, B and C would do. The point is, how do  I refer to B in the next sentence without repeating the same phrase  I used fo B in the fist sentence.

@EdwinAshworth Of course in the two examples in my comment I could just change the order "B was walking with A when..." followed by "The former..." or "... a bench, C and B stopped to greet him" followed by "The latter..." .  Hence the example in my question.

Yes, your question is well expressed. I'm just giving a typical workaround as I believe an idiomatic answer doesn't exist. 'The person mentioned second' or 'the addressee' are clarifying but clunkified.

Honestly, former and latter are not all that shorter than long names. Writers think they are doing us a favor, but an extra word here and there can be simpler. While we don't have to 'ordinalize' names to refer to the second or middle individual, is that more helpful than repeating the long name? Referring to 'the second name' will guarantee the reader has to go back for a look as to who that character was.

John Henry Adams Morgan Smith: Smith OR Mr. Smith. What the heck is the issue? :)

@Lambie  I just find the repetition "Bob Shaftoe was not addressing John Churchill but discussing him with Captain Barnes. Also Churchill was not yet Duke of Marlborough but at that time only Earl." rather ugly..

You can just use the last name in serious writing. You needn't use the first name at all after it was mentioned once. Shaftoe was not addressing Churchill but discussing him with the captain. At the time, Churchill was not yet Duke of Marlborough but only an earl at the time.

Repetition is more useful than saying "go look back and find who I mentioned second in the previous sentence". Rewriting is probably the best option: you should avoid introducing irrelevant details (people's changes of title) that only confuse the reader. It's better to refer to one person by one name.

Using twice the name "Churchill", first time with the first name, then without, seems the best option. The title is by no way irrelevant, since the title "Earl" was used (by Barnes) in the discussion with Shaftoe, while it was important (for me) to specify that this particular "John Churchill" was to become the first Duke of Marlborough.

You could refer to their numerical place in the enumeration. If there were three parties in the names list, then in the next phrase you say that the first guy is describing the second guy to the third (actually using the ordinal). It would work even for longer enumerations -- fourth, fifth etc.
Please keep in mind that this will only work right in that context, while the order of items (names) in the enumeration is still fresh in the reader's mind.
It will even work regardless of their actual order:

Fourth, third and sixth guys from a larger group of 8 are taken a separate room. There, Fourth slaps Third in front of Sixth.

You are correct in that using former and latter won't work. If the enumeration has more than two elements, former will refer to the first element (A) and latter will refer to the last one (C), with no possibility to reference B. The English language does not provide other mechanisms.

In the case of an enumeration,  I would of course use the ordinal. But in this case there is no enumeration, but rather, three people each having a different role in the sentence, the speaker (subject), the person described (object), the person to whom the description is told. So "the second one" would not work very well.  In fact, in French, it is even worse. We do have "ce dernier" for "the latter" but "le premier" would no sound so good for a subject, say, preceding the object. Though of course an ordinal would work for an enumeration.

While this is linguistically possible for longer lists, it's not very practical, as it requires the listener to keep the full list order in mind to understand the following sentences.

@Barmar  I was not thinking in terms of a spoken statement, but only in writing. And not for very long lists. Mostly for three people, subject, object, person spoken to. I asked this question here because of a question I wanted to ask in another community. I wanted to ask something about a person described by a first one to a third party in my previous sentence. I repeated the name, and this made me wonder if, since "former" and "latter" were excluded, there was maybe a better choice.

@Alfred I understand your question, my comment was because the answer refers to longer lists, like the example with the group of 8.

This really raises my red flags...

I would prefer that you restate B's name, rather than my having to go back and check which person was second in the list.  It reduces the cognitive load on the reader.
